# Trying to add ExtJS component to javascript code

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

We are adding ExtJS to legacy code, which means we don't have the luxury of making it a pure ExtJS application.

I am having difficulty understanding the concepts of ExtJS Components and Elements.

Inbetween the EXT-JS comments here, I want to implements lots of GUI goodness!

```
Ext.onReady (function () {


    var div = document.createElement('div');



    //////////EXT-JS//////////////////////

    var myDiv = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{

    })


    //add lots and lots of cool widgets here to myDiv!!!!!!!


    ///////////EXT-JS/////////////////////////////


    div.appendChild(myDiv); //:(

    document.body.appendChild(div);


});
```

The only precondition is that it follows the javascript code before and after.

The line **div.appendChild(myDiv)** does not appear to work because it is expecting a javascript node, and myDiv is a fancy ExtJS object (a component rather than an element?).

The error at this line i get is :

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The
>   new child element is null.

I tried **myDiv.render(div)** and that also doesn't work (and it also breaks the legacy pattern).

fiddle :

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/69d

Comment: You can't do that. Ext components aren't DOM nodes, so you can't treat them as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.create('Ext.Panel', ...)` is not returning a DOM node, it's returning an instance of `Ext.Panel`.

The native DOM API obviously does not know how to handle an ExtJS object.

You can however use the [`renderTo`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-renderTo) configuration option when instantiating a component in order the specify it's container.

*Note: You should not be using `renderTo` to nest ExtJS components.*

> Specify the id of the element, a DOM element or an existing Element
>   that this component will be rendered into. -
>   http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-renderTo

```
var yourPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    title: 'My Panel',
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: div
});
```

Comment: that sounds good, but it has to fit in with the code above. Everything outside the comments cannot be modified

Comment: @OliverWatkins I do not see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think using the [`render`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-render) function as you already suggested should be the correct approach.

However, there are two potential problems here:

- You need to make sure that the component is not rendered earlier already, i.e. make sure to omit the `renderTo` config
- Apparently it does not work if your `div` has not been rendered to the DOM yet, i.e. you'd need to append `div` first and then render your panel to it

Check out [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/69e) for a demonstration.

Comment: yes it seems that you can only render after appending to the document object